# I am having an issue with Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I am new to discord.js and I am wondering how to fix this error. Could you please fix my code and then also tell me how to avoid this issue in the future? Thanks!

**Code:**

```
client.on('message', message => {
if (message.content === '-ping') {
    const embed = {
        "title": "**Ping Results**",
        "fields": [
          {
            "name": "Bot",
            "value": "" +(botMsg.createdAt - message.createdAt) + "ms"
          },
          {
            "name": "API ",
            "value": Math.round(client.ping) + "ms"
          },
          {
            "name": "Uptime",
            "value": msToTime(client.uptime) + "ms"
          }
        ]
      };
      message.channel.send({ embed });
}
```

});

**Console Error:**

```
ReferenceError: botMsg is not defined
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\index.js:15:31)
at Client.emit (events.js:314:20)
at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
at WebSocket.emit (events.js:314:20)
at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\parke\Documents\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:797:20)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that the variable `botMsg` is not defined.

As I can see you want to make a ping command and botMsg is a message sent that you want to collect.

This code should work.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === '-ping') {
    message.channel.send("Checking the ping...").then(botMsg => {
        const embed = {
            "title": "**Ping Results**",
            "fields": [
              {
                "name": "Bot",
                "value": "" +(botMsg.createdAt - message.createdAt) + "ms"
              },
              {
                "name": "API ",
                "value": Math.round(client.ping) + "ms"
              },
              {
                "name": "Uptime",
                "value": msToTime(client.uptime) + "ms"
              }
            ]
          };
          botMsg.edit({ embed });
    })
  }
});
```